# Need to use left join with limit but it works wrong

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite

I have two sql query:

**1)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id  
FROM sh_itemviews WHERE login='".$login."' 
ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 5"
```

**2)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM sh_item WHERE id=itemIdFrom  sh_itemviews "
```

So i want to do it better and i'm trying to use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM sh_itemviews 
      LEFT JOIN sh_item ON sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id; 
WHERE sh_itemviews.login='".$login."' 
ORDER by sh_itemviews.time DESC LIMIT 5"
```

Like a result i have all data where sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id; but other constructin WHERE is ignored.
What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra **semi column** before the **WHERE** clause was the reason, Find the updated query below

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * 
 FROM sh_itemviews 
      LEFT JOIN sh_item ON sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id 
 WHERE sh_itemviews.login='".$login."' 
 ORDER by sh_itemviews.time DESC LIMIT 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon just before the `WHERE` statement.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sh_itemviews LEFT JOIN sh_item ON sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id**;** WHERE sh_itemviews.login='".$login."' ORDER by sh_itemviews.time DESC LIMIT 5"
```

The correct one is:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM sh_itemviews 
LEFT JOIN sh_item ON sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id 
WHERE sh_itemviews.login='".$login."' 
ORDER by sh_itemviews.time DESC 
LIMIT 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You make incorrect syntax before where
Try  this  syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM sh_itemviews 
LEFT JOIN sh_item ON sh_item.id = sh_itemviews.item_id

WHERE sh_itemviews.login='".$login."' 
ORDER by sh_itemviews.time DESC
LIMIT 5"
```

Comment: the answer required formatting but I just saw its an identical answer to one posted 20 minutes earlier than yours. May be due to reviewing first question. Anyway.. I did some reformatting for you.